# Multires Modifier undo/revert brush?

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

I have a low poly model that looks nice. I use the Multires modifier to subdivide it and sculpt extra detail in some parts of the mesh. Now i discover that i messed up a part. Can i "undo" parts of the multires sculpt like with a brush thats called revert to original subdivision. I can of course always remove the whole modifier and restart adding detail, or try to resculpt the messed up part, but its very difficult to do this if you want to stay as close as possible to the low poly mesh.

Is there an addon that lets you do that in a convenient way? Or a built in feature that I overlooked?

How do you do it? Is there a different workflow that allows you to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the [Multires Displacement Eraser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/multires_displacement_eraser.html) brush? If it doesn't help you still can switch to *Edit* mode, select the bad area, and separate the mesh. Then remove the *MultiRes* modifier from the separated mesh object and join it again with the original mesh object. Make sure the original mesh object is the *active* object (selection order, highlighted in *orange*) so the result gets the *MultiRes* modifier.

Comment: Thank you. Seriously why did I not see that brush? That does exactly what I want. And the workaround for people too blind to see that modifier (me) the detach and join also works :) If you make it an answer i would check it.

Comment: Don't mention it. Glad to read that it worked for you :-) The brush is a bit hidden and you have to scroll down a little to find it. Maybe that's the reason you missed it. I've forgotten the last step of the workaround. You should merge the meshes after you joined them again because of the now duplicated vertices. I've added it to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Multires Displacement Eraser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/multires_displacement_eraser.html) brush to restore the low-poly base mesh.

[image: screenshot]

If it doesn't help you still can try the following workaround:

- switch to *Edit* mode
- select the vertices of the bad area and separate the mesh with <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate* > *Selection*
- select the separated mesh object, and remove the *MultiRes* modifier from it
- now join it again with the original mesh object. Make sure the original mesh object is the *active*<sup>1)</sup> object so the result gets the *MultiRes* modifier.
- now there are duplicated vertices where you had separated the meshes. This can cause problems. So switch to *Edit* mode, select the vertices that you want to merge (or everything), and weld the meshes with a <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* operation. Otherwise, the separated mesh is still a loose part after you joined them.

Note 1): The *active* object is usually the one that you selected last in the viewport. It's highlighted in orange, while the *selected* object(s) are highlighted in red. Only the *active* object keeps its modifiers when you join objects.