# Unwanted crease at higher levels of the MuliRes modifier

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

Who can help me and tell me why is it so strange?

In *Edit* mode, my topology looks fine, but in the multi-Level precision display, it becomes bad.

There is a *MultiRes* modifier added, and that should be the problem. But after I repaired the damaged surface in the *Sculpt* mode, and changed the form key, I went back to the old days, and even the base type was changed.[image][image]

Comment: It looks like you may need to recalculate your normals (Select all > Ctrl+Shift+N). Also, on the topside of the right eye corner, there is a quad that looks like 2 differently shaded triangles put together - this is a non-planar face, and will cause issues with shading and possibly other things as well - try to correct it - one way is to select "normal" as the transform pivot point, then select the 4 vertices encompassing the non-planar face and scale "inwards".

Comment: The normal directions are all correct, and the topology of the eye part does have some problems in the combination. But I don't quite understand what you mean by the last sentence.

Comment: It's just a way to correct non-planar faces - see here for a more detailed description - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119874/how-can-i-manually-fix-nonplanar-geometry. It's hard to tell what else is going on with your object - for better assistance, consider uploading your file here - https://blend-exchange.com/ and posting the link into your question, so users here can have a look at it.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to BSE. A few expressions in your question are hard to understand. It may be a translation or language problem and not the right terms. I suspect that *"multi-level accuracy"* means *"MultiRes modifier"* and *"engraving mode"* is the *"Sculpt"* mode. But what do you mean by *"...and even the base type was changed"*? What is the "base type"? -- Anyway, I think it's a MultiRes + sculpting problem This can happen sometimes. There is a brush to remove the edited higher levels. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278332/107598