# Retopology after baking. My shrinkwrap modifer is causing spikes to come out in certain places. How can I fix this? I also have multires modifier on

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-baking, shrinkwrap, multiresolution

[image]

I am trying to regain details after baking. I tried to use shrink-wrap modifier, but it is causing spikes to come out the hands. I tried to use the distance limit, but it makes the low poly mesh become bloated.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278332/107598